# JEditorPane font size not setting precisely

Tags: java, swing, wysiwyg, jeditorpane

Im implementing a WYSIWYG html editor. 
 Im refering [this](https://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=1&thread=1276) HTMLEditor example.
 But there different predefined action instances are used for different menuItems.

I have a JCombobox in which font sizes are mentioned

```
fontSizeJComboBox.setModel(
    new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] 
    { "10", "12", "14", "16", "18", "20", "24", "28", "32", "36", "42", "48" }));

     fontSizeJComboBox.addActionListener(customFontSizeAction);
```

on font selection its action listener is invoking

```
class CustomFontSizeAction extends StyledEditorKit.FontSizeAction {

        public CustomFontSizeAction() {
            super(fontSizeJComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                    Integer.parseInt(fontSizeJComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString()));
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            JEditorPane editor = getEditor(ae);
            if (editor != null) {
                int fontSize = Integer.parseInt(fontSizeJComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());

                if (fontSize != 0) {
                    MutableAttributeSet attr = new SimpleAttributeSet();
                    StyleConstants.setFontSize(attr, fontSize);
                    setCharacterAttributes(editor, attr, false);
                } else {
                    UIManager.getLookAndFeel().provideErrorFeedback(editor);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But when i check if correct font size is applied? or **on CaretPosition update i want to reselect the jCombobox to specific font size, i do not get same number.**

```
CaretListener caretListener = new CaretListener() {
        @Override
        public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
            AttributeSet attributeSet = ((StyledEditorKit) commentTextArea.getEditorKit()).getInputAttributes();

            Object bold = attributeSet == null ? null : attributeSet.getAttribute(StyleConstants.Bold);
            if (bold != null && Boolean.parseBoolean(bold.toString())) {
                // enable bold button
            }

            Object italic = attributeSet == null ? null : attributeSet.getAttribute(StyleConstants.Italic);
            if (italic != null && Boolean.parseBoolean(italic.toString())) {
                // enable italic button
            }


            Object underline = attributeSet == null ? null : attributeSet.getAttribute(StyleConstants.Underline);
            if (underline != null && Boolean.parseBoolean(underline.toString())) {
                // enable underline button
            }

            Object fontSize = attributeSet == null ? null : attributeSet.getAttribute(StyleConstants.FontSize);

            if (fontSize != null && Integer.parseInt(fontSize.toString()) > 0) {

             fontSizeJComboBox.setSelectedItem(fontSize);

            }

            jLabel1.setText("" + fontSize);
            System.out.println("Font Size = " + fontSize);
        }
    };
```

Please help.

Comment: you have to set for HighLighter, note is required to test before in selection if Highlighter isn't used, if yes you have to loop in arrays from HighLighter (by using instanceof), real coordinates returns model to view or vice versa depends of direction

Comment: i dont get you.. can you elaborate ?